# Define IP address in string and replace last octet

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an IP address in my code Python 3.0 and I want to replace last octet to 0.

For example, `host = 10.10.10.15` to `host_changed = 10.10.10.0`

Comment: `host = '10.10.10.15'
    host = host.split('.')
    host[-1] = '0'
    host ='.'.join(host)`

Comment: Please show your efforts to solve this problem, and come back with any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ip` is a string, you can use `'.'.join(ip.split('.')[:-1]+["0"])`

For instance,

```
>>> ip = '10.123.43.15'
>>> '.'.join(ip.split('.')[:-1]+["0"])
'10.123.43.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.rfind()`

The `rfind()` method finds the last occurrence of the specified value.

```
host = "10.10.10.15"
host = host[:host.rfind('.')+1] + '0'
print (host)
```

output:

```
10.10.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
host = "10.10.10.15"

host_list = host.split(".")[:-1]
host_list.append("0")
host = ".".join(host_list)
print(host)
```

Output:

```
10.10.10.0
```